# Fake MLA-style bibliography fix?

Tags: bibliographies, indentation, automation, mla-style

```
\leftskip0.5in \parindent-0.5in Author. Title. Place: Publisher, Date. Medium.
```

convincingly fakes the hanging indent of MLA-style bibliography. Is there a way to set this for a region at every new paragraph within the region so as to not have to repeat it at every new entry? At the moment I have this kind of thing going on

```
\leftskip0.5in \parindent-0.5in Albert, Leonard. “Gnomonology: Joyce’s ‘The Sisters’.” \textit{James Joyce Quarterly} 27.2 (1990): 355–364. PDF.

\leftskip0.5in \parindent-0.5in Aristotle. \textit{The Poetics}. Trans. W. Hamilton Frye. Cambridge: Harvard UP, 1927. Print. Loeb Classical Library 199, Aristotle 23. 

\leftskip0.5in \parindent-0.5in Attridge, Derek. “Unpacking the Portmanteau, or Who’s Afraid of \textit{Finnegans Wake}?” \textit{On Puns: The Foundation of Letters}. Ed. Jonathan Culler. Oxford: Blackwell, 1988. 140–155. Print.
```

and I'd rather just define it once. Thanks!

Comment: You actually need to say that only once. Enclose the whole thing in a group.

Comment: You could use a customized list-like environment, but why don't you use a `.bib` database and `bibtex` or `biblatex`?

Comment: Thanks egreg! Gonzalo: I'm new to LaTeX, found biblatex-mla difficult to setup, and don't have time right now to figure it out. Zotero copy-paste works fine so far, but I imagine I'll move to .bib eventually once I have more free time. Just needed a quick fix and egreg's snippet works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only necessary to say that once. If you are using LaTeX, then an environment form for that might be

```
\newenvironment{fakemlabib}
  {\par\leftskip=0.5in \parindent=-\leftskip}
  {\par}
```

and then

```
\begin{fakemlabib}
Albert, Leonard. “Gnomonology: Joyce’s ‘The Sisters’.” \textit{James Joyce Quarterly} 27.2 (1990): 355–364. PDF.

Aristotle. \textit{The Poetics}. Trans. W. Hamilton Frye. Cambridge: Harvard UP, 1927. Print. Loeb Classical Library 199, Aristotle 23. 

Attridge, Derek. “Unpacking the Portmanteau, or Who’s Afraid of \textit{Finnegans Wake}?” \textit{On Puns: The Foundation of Letters}. Ed. Jonathan Culler. Oxford: Blackwell, 1988. 140–155. Print.
\end{fakemlabib}
```

will do.

With Plain TeX,

```
\par\begingroup
\leftskip=0.5in \parindent=-\leftskip
Albert, Leonard. “Gnomonology: Joyce’s ‘The Sisters’.” \textit{James Joyce Quarterly} 27.2 (1990): 355–364. PDF.

Aristotle. \textit{The Poetics}. Trans. W. Hamilton Frye. Cambridge: Harvard UP, 1927. Print. Loeb Classical Library 199, Aristotle 23. 

Attridge, Derek. “Unpacking the Portmanteau, or Who’s Afraid of \textit{Finnegans Wake}?” \textit{On Puns: The Foundation of Letters}. Ed. Jonathan Culler. Oxford: Blackwell, 1988. 140–155. Print.
\par\endgroup
```

Comment: Wonderful! Worked perfectly!